# ERROR_UNKNOW_URL_SCHEME ionic 3 auth0 with facebook

Tags: ionic3

I am working on a project ionic 3. and I intend to integrate auth0 authentication with facebook. But I get this error: ERROR_UNKNOW_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can reproduce this and see where could be the problem? Without that, what I can tell you is to check for urls without "http/https".

Comment: I have read in several forums where we say that the error is in the plugin CustumUrlScheme. here is my custumUrlScheme value in the config.xml file: <plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="^4.3.0">
        <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="jodim.testionic.app" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SCHEME" value="jodim.testionic.app" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_HOST" value="jodim.auth0.com" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_PATHPREFIX" value="/cordova/jodim.testionic.app/callback" />
    </plugin>

Answer (score 0):

for facebook login you should use the following custom url scheme in your config

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="^4.3.0">
      <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="your bundle ID" />
      <variable name="ANDROID_SCHEME" value=" " />
      <variable name="ANDROID_HOST" value=" " />
      <variable name="ANDROID_PATHPREFIX" value="/" />
    </plugin>
```